# Jdom element handling

Tags: xml, jdom

Is it possible somehow to nest an element into another if the parent has some text in it with jdom? What im looking for is something like `<p> text <str>bold text</str> text </p>`. I can create a new element called `<p>` and then with `.addContent` i can add a `<strong>` element under it but how can i do it if there is some text in the `<p>` element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve and remove the original text, identify the region that should be emphasized, split the original string around this region, add the prefix (if any), create and add an Elemen("strong")  and set its text to the region, and finall add the suffix (if any).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Element p = new Element("p");
    p.setText("Some bold text");
    print(p);
    List<Content> parts = split(p.getText());
    p.removeContent();
    p.addContent(parts);
    print(p);
}

static List<Content> split(String s) {
    List<Content> result = new LinkedList<Content>();
    String bold = "bold";
    int i = s.indexOf(bold);
    if (i != -1) {
        result.add(new Text(s.substring(0, i)));
        result.add(new Element("strong").setText(bold));
        result.add(new Text(s.substring(i+bold.length())));
    } else {
        result.add(new Text(s));
    }
    return result;
}

static void print(Element e) throws IOException {
    new XMLOutputter().output(e, System.out);
    System.out.println();
}
```